# Yahoo Finance Package installation in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, yahoo-finance

I am trying to install Yahoo Finance Package from Anaconda Cloud with the below CMD Line instruction

```
pip install -i http://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple yahoo-finance
```

But I am getting an error, not sure how to bypass. Please help

[image]

If I do

```
pip install yahoo-finance
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried python -m pip install yahoo-finance to install it to anaconda. Worked fine for me.

Comment: @Peter234 - In which folder have you downloaded the Yahoo-Finance file? I have the Yahoo-Finance package downloaded but pip not able to install

Comment: I haven't downloaded the file manually. I dit only the pip command nothing more.

Comment: Just do `pip install yahoo-finance`

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.5 in Anaconda

Comment: For me it works with python 3.5 in Anaconda... Try to download the zip file from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4. Extract it and then type: python setup.py install.

Answer (score 9):

Just run this command on Anaconda prompt:

```
pip3 install yfinance
```

Comment: that just worked for me in anaconda.

Answer (score 7):

```
conda install -c conda-forge yfinance
```

Comment: was having the same issue - 'conda install -c conda-forge finance' worked fine in installig the yfinance package.

Answer (score 2):

Below code:

```
 python -m pip install yahoo-finance
```

works well

Version of Python: 3.7

Typing in : Anaconda Prompt

Comment: What does it mean to type in the anaconda prompt? Does this mean that in the terminal, the working directory is the anaconda app?

Comment: @Dion Anaconda Prompt is in Windows. Simple terminal is used in Linux.  You can find details here https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/#:~:text=Anaconda%20Prompt I ran the command pip3 install yfinance in opened terminal in Ubuntu under default location. It's worked good

Answer (score 1):

```
conda install -c postelrich yahoo-finance
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

The simple command usually works:

```
pip install yahoo-finance
```

If this does not work usually anaconda has good packages that work with each other:

```
conda install yahoo-finance
```

Things that could introduce problems that are not solved by the above commands:

1. Python is not properly installed. Reinstall python. I would recommend using anaconda to install Python, because it has a lot of libraries pre-installed that do not conflict with each other.
2. Problems with the internet connection. Make sure that you have connection to the internet and specifically to pypi website (https://pypi.org/)
3. You do not have ssl libraries installed and that does not allow you to connect using https. Install ssl libraries.

Based on the error I would recommend reinstalling Python with Anaconda and checking your internet connection.